# How to use selectOneButton without primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need help answering this question. How to use selectOneButton without primefaces?

Comment: Have you tried with `h:selectOneRadio` plus css style?

Comment: I dont know how to use css with selectOneRadio, can you please help me out WoAiNii.